# Python Flask : Returned file is not readable

Tags: python, flask, response, flask-restful, sendfile

While implementing a rest API in python flask, I have used several options to return a file (any type) , read it and save it to local repository of request but encountered with multiple errors as below:

Case 1:

`def download_file(): 
     return send_file('any_file.pdf')
r = requests.get(url = 'http://localhost:5000/download').read()`

has responded with a error **Response object has no attribute read/text/content**

Case 2:

`def download_file(): 
     file = open('any_file.pdf','r').read()
     return file
r = requests.get(url = 'http://localhost:5000/download')`

has responded with a error **Return doesn't accept this**

So How can I do this as flask is not allowing to return a file without response object and response object is not readable and doesn't support to save that file directly.

Comment: I think, you missed scheme ***http://** 0.0.0.0:5000/download*

Comment: Yes you are right. Edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flask **server** code in `Case 1` is correct.  A more complete example:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download_file():
    # Some logic here
    send_file('any_file.pdf')
```

However the [`Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response) object returned by `requests.get` doesn't have a `read` method.  The correct way is to use:

> `Response.content`:  Content of the response, in bytes.

So, the **client** code should be:

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/download')
bytes = r.content

# Now do something with bytes, for example save it:

with open('downloaded_file.ext', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes)
```

Comment: I will check this.

Comment: That's is working for me but file contents are not properly stored in storage.

Comment: @ShahMuhammadTalha Sorry, can you expand on 'not properly stored in storage'... What behaviour are you seeing?